# How old are the oldest 12% of readers of this paper? The inverse of a Normal.

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem said,

> The ages of subscribers to a certain newspaper are normally
>   distributed with mean
>   $35.5$ years and standard deviation $4.8$.
>
> (a) What percentage of readers are between $30$ and $40$ years old?

I have: mean$=35.5$
        std$=4.8$

And $P(30<x<40)=P((30-35.5)/4.8<z<(40-35.5)/4.8)=0.699817 = 69.9817\%...$

> (b) How old are the oldest $12\%$ of readers of this paper?

$P(X>x)=0.12$
  I try to use the mean of $35.5$ and sed $4.8$ in my calculator to obtain the value of the age required, but it is not right due to the answer book said$=41.14$ years.

**What is the correct way to solve this point (b)?. Thanks!**

Comment: Hint, you have to solve $f(x)=P([x,\infty))=0.12$. A TI 84+ has a InvNorm option which can be used for this.

Comment: I used the invNorm(0.12,35.5,4.8)=29.8601  it is not the same as the value given by the book. And I don't know where is my mistake. Did you put, the same input in your TI84+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have take =NORMSINV(0.88) = 1.1749.

(100-.12) = (0.88) in the formula

Then the oldest age which is 12% is $X = 35.5+1.1749*35.5 = 41.14$